# How to use the Clients ip address within the function included in the server program?

Tags: c, sockets

I have written a C socket program. In my server program i have included a function called *data_process()*

My question is

The server program gets the clients ip address and writes into *info_agent_report.txt* file.

I need to use that ip address in the *data_process()* program*(which is included in the server program*) which creates *task_agent_report.csv* file.

Can i use it? (i have used but its not displaying the ip address in *task_agent_report.csv*file!!)

Could anybody help me out .

My server and data_process() program is as follows

```
int main()
{
  //intialization
  //....
  struct sockaddr_in client_address;
  if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0)
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  address.sin_port = htons(9734);
  server_len = sizeof(address);
  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, server_len);

  listen(sockfd, 5);
  while (1)
  {
    char ch;

    client_len = sizeof(client_address);

    new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address,
        &client_len);

    if (new_sockfd == -1)
    {
      perror("Connection Not Accepted!!");
      return (1);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("..");
      //to dispaly ip address
      FILE* ta_address = fopen("info_agent_report.txt", "a+");
      fprintf(ta_address, "%s,", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr));
      fclose(ta_address);

      log = open("info_agent_report.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0777);
      if (log == -1)
      {
        perror("cannot open info_agent_report file\n");
        return (1);
      }

      do
      {
        x1 = read(new_sockfd, buffer1, 1024);
        x2 = write(log, buffer1, x1);
      } while (x1 > 0);
      close(log);
      close(new_sockfd);
    }

    data_process();
  }
}
//i need to use the ip address in this function
```

data_process program:

```
void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* , int);
void print_ip_header(unsigned char*, int);
void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char *, int);
void print_udp_packet(unsigned char *, int);
void print_icmp_packet(unsigned char*, int);
void PrintData(unsigned char*, int);

FILE *logfile;

int data_process()
{
  //intialising...   
  unsigned char *buffer3 = (unsigned char *) malloc(1024);

  //i tried to print the ip address on the terminal but it din't

  struct sockaddr_in client_address;
  printf("print on the terminal from info agent%s\n",
      inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr));

  infile = open("info_agent_report.txt", O_RDONLY);
  if (infile == -1)
  {
    perror("cannot open info_agent_report file\n");
    return (1);
  }

  logfile = fopen("task_agent_processed.csv", "w+");
  if (logfile == NULL)
  {
    printf("Unable to create task_agent_processed file.");
  }

  do
  {
    data_size = read(infile, buffer3, 1024);
    print_tcp_packet(buffer3, data_size);

  } while (data_size > 0);

  fclose(logfile);
  close(infile);
  return 0;
}

void print_tcp_packet(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
  //initialization,structure.... 

  //i need to use the ip address in the csv file to display it in the same row   

  fprintf(logfile, "%s,%d,%u\n", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr), 1,
      ntohs(tcph->source));
}
```

Comment: Compile with symbols and run the program using a debugger inspecting step by step what happens to the variables involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program not in proper structure. you are getting client address in 
`client_address` variable in main() program.

Then you are calling `data_process()` function, there you again freshly declaring `client_address` variable and trying to get ip address from that local variable, but this local variable will not contain any valid information about client.

If you want to get ip address in `data_processing()` function, then you have to make `struct sockaddr_in client_address`variable declaration global or else pass this variable to `data_processing()`.

I think you are trying to display packet details like packet sniffer. use can try with RAW SOCKET this will make your work easy. [man 7 raw](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw)

Comment: just declaring struct sockaddr_in client_address globally solves my problem? i mean can i access the ip address in my dataprocess() program?

Comment: yes you can get, remove the the declaration from main() and dataprocess() and put it globally. i compiled your program i got that.

Comment: yes exactly its a packet sniffer program. Do you know how to calculate time for every captured packets?

Comment: @user3040523 you want packet captured time?

Comment: Yes i need captured time for every packet. I have used Time stamp but its not working.

Comment: @user3040523 use time() function, when receiving the packet

Comment: i used gettimeofday() function ,but same time is getting displayed for every received packet.

Comment: @user3040523 can you give the link of your full code? then i can try to find what is the problem.

Comment: Ya Its here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603794/print-the-packet-captured-time-using-c-socket-program] I don't know how to print the captured time for every packet :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your issue, but why don't you use the value in memory instead of writing/read it from a file?

```
char* ip_addr;
// ...
ip_addr = inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr);
// ...
data_process(ip_addr);
```

From the man page, the char* returned by `inet_ntoa` is statically allocated. It means there is a static pointer holding the value for you. It also means that the value at this same address will change each time you call `inet_ntoa`.
If you somehow need to call `inet_ntoa` while you still need the pointer, copy the value in another buffer (typically with `strcpy` and a char[16])